# Error while calling a method in IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps

i'm using google API for showing my pins in my map. For this i call a method in viewDidLoad method to show my pins fetch from google into my map when map loads. I have call my method like this,

```
[self performSelector:@selector(pinn:)];
```

But when i open the map it shows an error and app crashes, i don't know why is it coming so.

[image]

Comment: Your JosnData is nil then application crash!! So Before call this method pass dictionary. use flowing code 

NSDictionary   * JsonData = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject: @"Crash Stop" forKey: @"Test"];

 [self performSelector:@selector(pinn:JsonData)];

Answer (score 0):

Here you need to pass the **JsonData** while calling this method. Because your `pinn:` method have a parameter. 
You need to call this method inside API response success from Google. And call like this:

```
[self pinn:<YOUR_JSON_DATA>]
```

`<YOUR_JSON_DATA>` can be response from the API, which you want to call and get the pins from google.

Comment: i'm calling it before so how can i get jsonData first. @Antony Raphel

Comment: from where you are getting pins?

Comment: i have static array in viewDidload above the call of method. @Antony Raphel

Comment: if you are not passing any values to that parameter, remove it.

Answer (score 0):

Your JosnData was getting nil that the reason application got crash!! 
while call this method pass the dictionary so use flowing code.

```
 NSDictionary * JsonData = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject: @"My lat and long" forKey: @"data"]; // Here pass your Jsondata dictionary.
 [self performSelector:@selector(pinn:JsonData)]; // Or pass here your dictionary.
```